# Saving data from textbox to MS Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

This is my first attempt at using a database, and I'm stuck here, not too sure what to do. Here is my code:

```
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public AddProfile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Caden\source\repos\PJBot\PJBot\bin\Debug\Profiles.mdb";
        connection.Open();

        //updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand updateQuery = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Profiles (FullName,ProfileName,Email,Password,CardNumber,EXPMonth,EXPYear,CVV) VALUES(@name1,@name2,@email,@pass,@card,@expm,@expy,@cvv)", connection);
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //Profile Name
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox2.Text; //Email
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox3.Text; //Pass
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text; //FullName
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@card", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text; //CardNumber
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expm", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox1.Text; //EXPMonth
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expy", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox2.Text; //EXPYear
        updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@cvv", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox7.Text; //CVV
        updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Profile Saved");
    }
```

I'm trying to have the user save his information to the database based on what the user inputs into the textbox.

Comment: what is the problem / exception you get?

Comment: OleDB requires the parameters to be in index order.  The names are actually ignored.

Comment: @rene I get this error:
System.FormatException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal.' on the updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery(); line when clicking the save button

Comment: Why would your email and passoword be numeric?  name1 should be the first parameter you add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your parameters should match that of the columns specified in your `INSERT` statement, hence:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand updateQuery = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Profiles (FullName,ProfileName,Email,Password,CardNumber,EXPMonth,EXPYear,CVV) VALUES(@name1,@name2,@email,@pass,@card,@expm,@expy,@cvv)", connection);
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text; //FullName
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@name2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //Profile Name
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox2.Text; //Email
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = textBox3.Text;  //Pass
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@card", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;  //CardNumber
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expm", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox1.Text; //EXPMonth
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@expy", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = comboBox2.Text; //EXPYear
    updateQuery.Parameters.Add("@cvv", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox7.Text;   //CVV
    updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Profile Saved");
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked after I changed the Types and put password in brackets :)